# Random value based on a condition given by other user

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to make a change in diet app where we have a list of meals created by the nutricionist so the user can get a different meal to eat based on a defined chance, for example:

```
Rice and egg = 40%
Rice and chicken = 40%
Free to choose = 10%
Rice and steak = 5%
Pasta and Fried chicken = 5%
```

I have a cool way to show it to the user but not an effective code to make the decision.

Would be glad if someone could help here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [this](https://www.techiedelight.com/generate-random-input-array-according-given-probabilities/#:%7E:text=Algorithm%3A,element%20from%20the%20input%20array) algo  to find a random meal according to given probabilities.

Implementation:

```kotlin
fun getRandomMeal(meals: List<String>, probabilities: List<Int>): String {
    val cumulativeProbabilities = probabilities.runningFold(0, Int::plus)
    val random = (1..100).random()
    meals.forEachIndexed { i, meal ->
        if (cumulativeProbabilities[i + 1] >= random)
            return meal
    }
    return ""
}
```

[Try it yourself](https://pl.kotl.in/vWng3ZU_2)